# When reflective spell resistance works against vampiric touch, what happens?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters, dnd-3e

The special ability *reflective spell resistance* of the nerra says

> A nerra has a special type of spell resistance that causes any targeted spell it successfully resists to bounce off and reflect back at the caster. The caster becomes either the spell’s target or the point of origin for the spell’s effect, as appropriate. In addition, nerras are immune to gaze attacks, and such an effect is reflected back to its origin. (*Fiend Folio* 127)

If a caster casts the spell [*vampiric touch*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/vampiricTouch.htm) and hits a nerra but the caster fails to overcome the nerra's reflective spell resistance, what happens? Who gains temporary hp and who loses hp?

---

***Note:*** Looking for [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) *answers; tagged* [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) *only because the* Fiend Folio *is originally for that edition.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The caster loses the HP...

#### Vampiric Touch

> ...Target: Living creature touched...
>
> ...Spell Resistance: Yes
>
> ...Your touch deals 1d6 points of damage per two caster levels (maximum 10d6). You gain temporary hit points equal to the damage you deal. However, you can’t gain more than the subject’s current hit points +10, which is enough to kill the subject. The temporary hit points disappear 1 hour later.

You, the caster, lose the HP and gain them as temporary HP that disappear 1 hour later. If the damage is enough to kill you, you have 1 hour to gain enough real, rather than temporary, HP back before you risk dying.

Comment: Do temporary HP alone permit you to be conscious? Can you provide a citation to confirm that receiving temporary HP while below 0 HP makes you conscious?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Since they're hp—albeit temporary—it would take rules saying *Temporary hp don't restore consciousness* to make it so temporary hp *don't* restore consciousness. For instance, the *RC* on temporary hp (72) mentions no difference between the effects of gaining *actual* as opposed to *temporary* hp when unconsciousness is involved, so a typical creature that gains temporary hp when at or below -1 hp regains consciousness normally.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I might be attaching 5e limits to 3.5. But I was under the impression that temps being described as 'similar' to normal hit points. As I don't have a PHB or anything available right now, I can't confirm, but this in itself may be worth a question on it's own.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Maybe? I dunno how temporary hp work in *5e*, but, yeah, [temporary hp](http://dndsrd.net/injuryAndDeath.html#temporary-hit-points) in *3.5e* are *like* regular hp *except* for the differences put forth in the link; nothing *else* changes. But don't let my stance stop you from posing the question! `:-)`

Comment: "It resolves just as if you were touching yourself."